# Laravel : Traying to get property 'posts' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I wanted to show posts from a user. But, I received an error message : ***Trying to get property 'posts' of non-object***

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    $user = User::find(5);
    return $user->posts;
});
```

Comment: are you sure that there is a user with id 5 in your database?

Comment: use `App\Post` instead of `Post::class` and `App\User` instead of `User::class`. it should be work (notice: you should give the address of your model which in the default mode it is in the 'App' folder, so it's address is `App\ModelName`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('test', function () {
   $user = User::where('id', 5)->with('posts')->get();
   return $user;
});
```

Comment: @SerdarPolat, You can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

What is the author a separate model?
First you need to create a proper migration, so that `user_id` is referenced as a foreign key in your posts table.

You should have a migration up method similiar to this:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

And your model can be something like this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user record associated with the post.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to call `$post->user`, for your use case I do not know what author is but you should be able to adapt my answe, good luck.

Comment: "author_id" means "user_id"

Comment: @SerdarPolat then please name it as `user_id`

Comment: @SerdarPolat you also need to rename your `author()` function to `user()` laravel does automatically detect it and compares it to existing models